# Usage of the Oxford Comma with "and"

Tags: punctuation, commas, oxford-comma

I was told that this sentence is correct with the usage of a comma before and after the word *and*.  I want to correct my grammar if I am in error.

> To claim a prize, send a Private Message to me stating: which prize
>   you won, your geographical location, and, if necessary, your address
>   for sending a physical prize.

Is the comma usage in this sentence correct?

Comment: Commas have nothing to do with grammaticality. This, sentence, right,here,is,,,, grammatically impec,,,ab,,le.

Answer (score 3):

That sentence is grammatically correct. This is because *if necessary* is a [subordinate clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_clause), not just another item in your comma-separated list.

Keep in mind, if you were to remove that subordinate clause from the sentence, you would **not** use a comma after the *and*:

> To claim a prize, send a Private Message to me stating: which prize you won, your geographical location, and your address for sending a physical prize.

Comment: This sentence retains the Oxford comma before _and_, and I'd say few people would omit it here. It disambiguates. I think most people would drop the colon, though. _To claim a prize, send a Private Message to me stating which prize you won, your geographical location, and (for a prize needing mailing) your address._

Comment: Both answers seem to have people that agree with them and they are against each other.