# Should I include a comma after a mid-sentence list of three things?

Tags: punctuation, commas, lists

For example, "Race, religion, and gender, are still crucial factor's in someone's success"

Should there be a comma after "gender"? And is this a fixed rule?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Usage of the Oxford Comma with "and"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/162087/usage-of-the-oxford-comma-with-and)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a comma necessary in "What’s funny, is …"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76850/is-a-comma-necessary-in-what-s-funny-is). See also [Commas between the subject and the verb / predicate – a mistake or acceptable?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/418555/commas-between-the-subject-and-the-verb-and-predicate-a-mistake-or-acceptable) and the linked threads.

Answer (score 1):

In a word, no. *Race, religion and gender* form a compound subject and are followed by the predicate (in this case a complement) *are still crucial factor's in someone's success*. There should be no comma between a subject and its predicate.

This is a fixed rule to the extent that all descriptive grammars and style guides that I am aware of proscribe the usage. There's a good summary of the issue, with citations from various reference sources, on the *[Sentence first](https://stancarey.wordpress.com/2017/11/01/adding-a-comma-between-the-subject-and-predicate-is-inadvisable/)*, with the exemplarily incorrect title:

> *Adding a comma between the subject and predicate, is inadvisable*

Here is a brief extract:

> Quirk and Greenbaum’s *University Grammar of English*, for example,
>   says categorically that a comma 'cannot separate subject from
>   predicate'.

And incidentally, *factors* is a simple plural, not a possessive. There should be no apostrophe.

Comment: "The New Oxford Guide to Writing By Thomas S. Kane {1988} doesn't accept the mantra 'Never separate the subject from its verb with a comma' as being an inviolable edict." appears in the duplicate thread.

Comment: Thank you for that. Ignore the "factors" bit, I'll put that down to a lack of sleep. So is that still true for the following sentence? "What with the time difference, dodgy WiFi connection, and my unpredictable schedule I think that a web-call will be almost impossible until my travels are finished." It just feels counter-intuitive to not add a comma after "schedule".

Comment: @Alex. The subject in the new sentence  you cite is _I_ and the simple predicate is _think_. You would certainly not write _I, think that..._. The words that end with _schedule_ form a prepositional phrase. These are commonly found at the beginning of sentences and marking them off with a comma is optional. If they are long compounds, as in your case, I might also end them with a comma. Some writers may also separate long, compound subjects from the predicate with a comma if they feel this aids reading. But in general this is a good rule to be aware of, if not always to follow.